# How to make JNDI look up optional in Spring

Tags: spring, jndi

Is there anyway where we can make the JNDI lookup optional in spring appllicationcontext xml configuration.

I want to deploy the same application which has JNDI setting(Data base connection) on two different environments. In one environment we need DB connection and another environment we don't need the DB connection. Could you please suggest if there is a away we can achieve this without modifying the applicationcontext.xml(I mean without commenting out the JNDI configuration and other related bean injection for DB connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use profiles, something like:

```
<beans profile="prod">
   <jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DatabaseName"expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</beans>

<beans profile="dev,default">
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
      <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
  </bean>type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</beans>
```

Then when you start you app say which profile with system argument:

```
-Dspring.profiles.actibe=prod
```

The default profile will be dev.